# How to update global data in clickMapObject listener from AmChart

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts

I'm learning about `AmChart js` lib and I have some doubts.

I have one map that show all devices registered in my database (look the print below)

[image]

So, I would like to implement one functionality for when the user clicks on the bubble from one country in the map, the table list is filtered by country, so, in the device, table should show only devices from the country of the bubble that user clicked.

for to do this filter when a user clicks in the bubble, I'm using the addListener from Amchart (`clickjMapObject`) as the example below.

```
 this.map.addListener('clickMapObject', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.deviceList).
 });
```

the console.log(event) it's working, but When I try to print `"deviceList"` not working. I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'devicesList' of undefined

I don't know if it's possible to access global array in the listener, So, I don't know what's the problem. Could you please help me?

follow my complete code below. (in this code you can see how to I populate the `"deviceList"`)

```
export class DevicesLocationComponent implements OnInit {

  public devicesList: Device[];
  public images = [];
  public country_location = [];
  public map: any;

  @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private deviceService: DeviceService) 
  {
    this.getCountryLocationJSON().subscribe(data => {
      this.country_location = data;
    });
  }


  /**
   * Build initial the chart and load devices location
   *
   * @memberof DevicesLocationComponent
   */
   public ngOnInit() {
     this.loadDeviceDataTable();
   }


   /**
    * This function is responsible to load datatable with devices data
    */
    private loadDeviceDataTable() {

      // load last used devices data
      this.deviceService.getAllDevices()
         .subscribe(((listDevices: Device[]) => {
              this.devicesList = listDevices;

             this.buildMapChart();   
      }));
    }

    /**
     * This function is responsible to build the map chart after load devices data on datatable.
     */
     private buildMapChart() {

        // get min and max values for define bubble size frm map chart
        const minBulletSize = 10;
        const maxBulletSize = 40;
        let min = Infinity;
        let max = -Infinity;
        for (const key in this.tardisDevicesGrouped) {
           if (this.tardisDevicesGrouped.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               const value = this.tardisDevicesGrouped[key].length;
               if ( value < min ) {
                  min = value;
               }
               if ( value > max ) {
                 max = value;
               }
           }
        }

       // it's better to use circle square to show difference between values, not a radius
      const maxSquare = maxBulletSize * maxBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;
      const minSquare = minBulletSize * minBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;

      // create circle for each country
      for (const key in this.tardisDevicesGrouped) {
        if (this.tardisDevicesGrouped.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const value = this.tardisDevicesGrouped[key].length;
          const country_location = this.getLatLongCountry(key);

          // calculate size of a bubble
         let square = ( value - min ) / ( max - min ) * ( maxSquare - minSquare ) + minSquare;
         if ( square < minSquare ) {
           square = minSquare;
         }
         const size = Math.sqrt( square / ( Math.PI * 2 ) );

         // set each bubble size, value and colors for each country
         this.images.push( {
         'type': 'circle',
         'theme': 'light',
         'width': size,
         'height': size,
         'longitude': country_location.longitude,
         'latitude': country_location.latitude,
         'color': country_location.color,
         'title': country_location.country_name,
         'selectable': true,
         'value': value
       });
     }
   }

   this.map = AmCharts.makeChart('allocation-map', {
     'type': 'map',
     'hideCredits': true,
     'theme': 'light',
     'colorSteps': 10,
     'dataProvider': {
       'map': 'worldLow',
       'images': this.images,
       'zoomLevel': 1.0,
       'zoomLongitude': 10,
       'zoomLatitude': 52
     },
     'areasSettings': {
        'autoZoom': true,
        'selectable': true
     }
   });

   console.log(this.devicesList);  // It's working 

   this.map.addListener('clickMapObject', function (event) {
     console.log(event);
     console.log(this.devicesList);   // It's not working
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above the event listener you should declare a variable storing the current scope

```
var self = this
```

Then inside the function triggered at the event you should change the this reference to self

```
console.log(self.devicesList);
```

At the end your code should look like this:

```
 console.log(this.devicesList);  // It's working 
 var self = this;
   this.map.addListener('clickMapObject', function (event) {
     console.log(event);
     console.log(self.devicesList);   // Now it will work
    });
  }
```

This happens because the scope is changing depending on where you are, so "this" doesn't mean the same inside an event listener than inside a component, the reference changes

Comment: Hi Osakr, I'm using typeScript. i'ts possible in typeScript? because I had declarated the deviceList as public variable.

Comment: This is as valid in typescript as it is in javascript. 'This' reference changes when the context is changed so when you do `var self = this` the only thing that you're doing is having another reference to your current scope and when the scope changes you will be able to keep doing things with that old scope (where all your component is)

Comment: You can do a console.log(this) before the event listener and then do a console.log(self) inside the event listener function. You'll see that is exactly the same

Comment: I get this error: [ts] Property 'devicesList' does not exist on type 'Window'. [2339]

Comment: Are you doing it inside buildMapChart function? Also, have you put the console.log of `this.devicesList` just before the `var self = this` (just for checking that the scope does have the devicesList )

Comment: yes. public self = this; and in method I do it: this.map.addListener('clickMapObject', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(self.tardisDevices);
      });

Comment: Don't use public, just declare it has a normal variable, `var self = this`. Can you show me what does your 'this' have in the moment you create the self variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184638/discussion-between-joh-and-osakr).