# Angular constructor doesn't set a local variable before ngOnInit() is called

Tags: javascript, angular

I am struggling with calling the backend from angular. When I create a component I also get the parameter "category" from the URL like this:

```js
export class ProductsComponent{

    productList = []
    category = ""

    $params;
    $products;

    constructor(
        private products: ProductsService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.$params = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params['category']
        });

        this.$products = this.products.products(this.category).subscribe(
            productList => {
                this.productList = productList.result
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        // DON'T FORGET TO UNSUBSCRIBE!!!
        this.$params.unsubscribe();
        this.$products.unsubscribe();
      }
}
```

This works well, but now in the ProductsService, where I call the http.get I think it is not working fine.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

    public products(category: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`/products/getallproducts`, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, params: {'category': category}})
    }
}
```

Because when I try to log the req.body.category in the backend, it says it is null. But it is not, it is the right value.

This is what I am trying to do in Node:

```js
products.get(('/getallproducts'), (req, res) => {
    let category = req.body.category;
    console.log("REQ" + req.body)

    if(category === "all") {
        ProductModel.findAll()
        .then(result => {
            res.json({result: result})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({error: err})
        })
    } else {
        ProductModel.findAll({
            where: {
                productsubcategory: category
            }
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.json({result: result})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({error: err})
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Take a look at this post, it might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598764/how-to-update-global-data-in-clickmapobject-listener-from-amchart

Comment: Let's solve this one by one. First move getting param code to the start of `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: I would take the part about the routing and ask in a separate question.

Comment: I agree with moving your routes question to a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Review this article: [Todd MoTTo: Angular constructor versus ngOnInit](https://toddmotto.com/angular-constructor-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook)

Then move your constructor code into your *ngOnInit* method.

```
// Add these;
$params;
$products;

constructor(
  private products: ProductsService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.$params = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.category = params['category']
  });

  this.$products = this.products.products(this.category).subscribe(
    productList => {
      this.productList = productList.result
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err)
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  // DON'T FORGET TO UNSUBSCRIBE!!!
  this.$params.unsubscribe();
  this.$products.unsubscribe();
}
```

> **Update**: I see what you're doing now. It appears to be a bit backwards to me. First you are loading the component, then going to *GET* some backend data. If you are routing to something new that requires some data, then try a resolver. With a resolver, you can fetch new data on route change. It is up to you if you want to pause the resolver until you get data (and have a spinner on the link that was clicked), or show a loading screen and wait for it. But the resolver will load when the route is loaded and it will publish the result. Then listen for the resolver Observable in the component.

```
// In Routes
{
  path: 'products/:category',
  component: YourComponent,
  resolve: {
    data: ProductsResolver
  }
},// rest of routes.

@Injectable()

export class ProductsResolver implements Resolve<any> {

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient
){}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
  return this.http.get('/products/getallproducts',
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      params: {
        'category': route.params.category
      }
    });
}
```

> And the component then would be...

```
$products;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.$products = this.route.data.subscribe(productList => {
    this.productList = productList.result;
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.$products.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Is it fine if I moved the code from ngOnInit in a function which I called from the constructor inside the subscribe?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. The point is that the constructor may be called way earlier than the route.params is completed, which when run in the constructor, will give you the immediate value of the route.params: undefined. You need to use the ngOnInit hook as it will run after your route params is set.

Comment: This works fine until here, but know seems that the way I call this.http.get with parameters it is not working. I will update the code in the post now.

Comment: I tried your routing configuration in stackblitz and it works for me.